# Is it possible to load Angular 2 components by dynamically changing their selector name?

Tags: angular

I have two Angular 2 components, `<future-todos>` and `<past-todos>`. Can I somehow load them dynamically as shown below?

**component.ts**

```
if (condition) {
    list = 'future';
} else {
    list = 'past';
}
```

**component.html**

```
<{{list}}-todos></{{list}}-todos>
```

My actual situation is more complex, and I've omitted a lot of code to simplify this example showing my needs.

Comment: Do not miss this [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But `NgSwitch` can be used in this case:

HTML:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="list">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="future">
        <future-todos></future-todos>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="past">
        <past-todos></past-todos>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Unrecognized list type</div>
</div>
```

Don't forget the default type